# How can I know how many elements are in the Paginated Models in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a query and called the following:

```
$elements = new PaginatedModels($query);
```

Then in view I have created a foreach to scroll through all the elements:

```
foreach ($elements->getModels() as $id => $element) :
```

If i do:

```
count($elements->getModels()
```

it displays Only the total number of elements on a page, I would like to know the total with all the pages.

Thanks

Comment: Does `PaginatedModels` return data provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it done

```
 $elements->getPagination()->totalCount
```

PaginationModels has a totalCount property that tells you how many elements in total it has